# Django server returning different status code

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework to implement a simple api. Inside my view.py I have this method:

```
def business_profile_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a profile.
    """
    try:
        profile = BusinessProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except BusinessProfile.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = BusinessProfileSerializer(profile)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        """
        Method not supported yet
        """
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        """
        Method not supported yet
        """
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

So for the PUT and DELETE methods, I want to return an error 405, but using the django test server, I keep getting an error 500:

```
[17/Oct/2014 18:20:22] "DELETE /business/api/profile/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 60487
```

Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

**EDITED:**

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/*******/Documents/dev/offers/project/offers/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "/Users/*******/Documents/dev/offers/project/offers/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7-py2.7.egg/django/template/response.py" in render
  103.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/Users/mariopersonal/Documents/dev/offers/project/offers/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in rendered_content
  49.         assert renderer, ".accepted_renderer not set on Response"

Exception Type: AssertionError at /business/api/profile/2
Exception Value: .accepted_renderer not set on Response
```

Comment: Some traceback there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `Response` class you're using there requires a data argument:

> Signature: `Response(data, status=None, template_name=None, headers=None, content_type=None)`

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses

I'd just use a basic `HttpResponse` there.